Need to add a particular row of column value to the another column with the same hierarchy
In SQL Server, I have input like this:



Id
Code
Description
July
August




1
1000
Input Taxes
NULL
NULL


2
1
Koshigaya
65755
48910


3
2
Dormitory
15994
25107


4
0
Business
23873
23813


5
NULL
Total
105622
97830


6
2014
Render Account
NULL
NULL


7
1
World Garden
65755
48910


8
0
Business
23873
23813


9
NULL
Total
89628
72723



I want a result output as shown below:



Code
Description
Property
July
August




1000
Input Taxes
Koshigaya
65755
48910


1000
Input Taxes
Dormitory
15994
25107


2014
Render Account
World Garden
65755
48910



I need to omit rows where code is 0 or Description is "Total".
Suppose the code has greater than three number then the description is follow as same as per given in output. But need to add extra column that is property and Property name is got from next row of there description but we have to specify a condition where code is between 1 to 2, 1 to 3, 1 to 4 and so on.

What, in your data, relates Input Taxes to Koshigaya? I see no relationship defined.

Is there another column which has a proper sequence (identity or row number)?

@thom A, there is no relationship but it's look like a Account Tree.  After the total there is second description like wise that you have to follow so on.

If there's no relationship, you cannot achieve what you are after, @AebdDr .

@John Cappelletti, yes there is identity column in input table( Source)

Tables are unordered sets, there is no first./last/before/after. If you can definitively say how to correlate these rows together then this is impossible. I would have expected a column such as ParentCode

There is no such thing in databases as the "next row". You cannot assume the database will give you the rows in this order every time. They are even free to re-order rows on disk!  You need to explain why one row comes after the other.

But if you can solve the ordering issue (hint: perhaps by id), this looks like a gaps and islands problem.

Here is one option using the window functions first_value() over() and sum() over()
Note:  This assumes CODE is a string and not an INT
Example
with cte as (
Select *
      ,grpCode        = first_value(Code)        over (Partition by Grp Order by ID)
      ,grpDescription = first_value(Description) over (Partition by Grp Order by ID)
 From  (
        Select *
              ,Grp = sum(case when len(Code)>=3 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by ID)
         From  YourTable
       ) A
)
Select Code        = grpCode
      ,Description = grpDescription
      ,Property    = Description
      ,July
      ,August
 From  cte
 Where len(Code)<3 and Code<>'0'

Results
Code    Description     Property        July    August
1000    Input Taxes     Koshigaya       65755   48910
1000    Input Taxes     Dormitory       15994   25107
2014    Render Account  World Garden    65755   48910


You might wanna add ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW to the SUM, this is a small perf. improvement
